# forum in rails 4.2.3

Tags: forum, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Can someone please tell me best way for developing forum, so that I can integrate it in my rails project. 
**Note:-  For rails- 4.2.3**
I have already tried forem and thredded, but they seem outdated or not well maintained(developed).

Comment: I don't know you have seen this or not https://github.com/radar/forem , but it is looking like they support rails4 . you can also fork it and developed for your application.

Comment: When I run bundle install I get this error:-
"Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    hublot (~> 0.0.4) ruby depends on
      rails (> 3.0.0) ruby

    forem (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (<= 4.2, ~> 4.0) ruby"

When I change my version to 4.2.1(rails), It still shows the "hublot" issue.

Comment: And obviously this if for forem ( github.com/radar/forem )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes people these days are developing forum using other tools. If you still want to built forum in rails you can refer http://www.sitepoint.com/forem-rails-forum-engine/

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

forem ( github.com/radar/forem ) does not work after rails 4.2. You can use https://mackenziechild.me/video/how-to-build-a-forum-with-rails-4/ if you want to make it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

[Thredded](https://thredded.org/) is a great forum engine, is actively developed, and is easy to integrate into any Rails app:

[image: Thredded demo screenshot]